# Randomize Keno Board

Tags: excel

Trying to create a keno board where a person can press a button and get 20 random highlighted numbers. The keno board goes from A1 to J10 and this is the code im using to randomize.

```
Sub GetRandomCell()

Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Do While i < 21

    Dim RNG As Range
    Set RNG = Range("A1:j10")

    Dim randomCell As Long
    randomCell = Int(Rnd * RNG.Cells.Count) + 1

    With RNG.Cells(randomCell)
        .Select
        .Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With

    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

The problem I am running into is it doesnt always generate 20 yellow cells. How do I ensure that there is always 20?

Comment: You're only selecting 1 of 20 numbers, and you're selecting 20 times. It's a high probability you'll get at least one repeated number, which means you're setting the same square(s) to yellow multiple times. If you want to avoid repeats, you're going to have to keep track of the ones you've actually used and not use them a second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub GetRandomCell()
Dim i       As Integer
Dim RNG     As Range
Set RNG = Range("A1:J10")
Dim randomCell As Long
i = 1
Do While i < 21
    randomCell = Int(Rnd * RNG.Cells.Count) + 1
    If RNG.Cells(randomCell).Interior.Color <> vbYellow Then
        RNG.Cells(randomCell).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

As mentioned by @KenWhite, it's possible (even probable with such a relatively small range) that you have a cell "overwriting" it's already yellow color.  Just add a test, as above, that first checks the cell color and *if not* yellow, then make yellow.

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could +1 both comments because both were extremely helpful.

Comment: @Gehn47 - Glad to help! A note too, it's generally a better idea to declare your variables outside of a loop, which I have done here. This is a small macro, so it's very unlikely you'd notice any performance issues, but just thought to mention.  There's no reason to set your range each individual loop, same with `Dim randomCell as Long`.